# jQuery script not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that I modify with jQuery, to change it's id and/or class. And when it has a spesific class and user clicks the button, it should execute the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $("#tilisiirtobtn").click(function() {
        alert("buttoni toimii");
        var Nimi =             $(".Nimi").val();
        var Osoite =           $(".Osoite").val();
        var Postinumero =      $(".Postinumero").val();
        var Postitoimipaikka = $(".Postitoimipaikka").val();
        var Puhelin =          $(".Puhelin").val();
        var Sahkoposti =       $(".Sahkoposti").val();
        var Filtteri =         /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        $('.error').hide();
        if(Nimi == ""){
            $(".Nimi").focus();
            $("#Nimi-error").show();
            return false;
        }
        if(Osoite == ""){
            $(".Osoite").focus();
            $("#Osoite-error").show();
            return false;
        }
        if(Postinumero == ""){
            $(".Postinumero").focus();
            $("#Postinumero-error").show();
            return false;
        }
        if(Postitoimipaikka == ""){
            $(".Postitoimipaikka").focus();
            $("#Postitoimipaikka-error").show();
            return false;
        }
        if(Puhelin == ""){
            $(".Puhelin").focus();
            $("#Puhelin-error").show();
            return false;
        }
        if(Sahkoposti == ""){
            $(".Sahkoposti").focus();
            $("#Sahkoposti-error").show();
            return false;
        }

        $('.supernappula').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      var data = $('#yhteystiedot').serializeArray();
      data.push( { name: 'cartContent', value: $('#emailedcart').html()});
      //alert (data);return false;
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: "order/order.php",
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){ if(confirm("Mitään ei näytä tapahtuvan. Päivitä sivu?") == true){ window.location.reload();} 
 },
    success: function() {
 alert("Onnistui");
        }


  });
  return false;

    });
  });        
});
```

However, it won't even execute the alert that is the first thing to do.

Here's the code that changes the id and class of the button:

```
$(function() {
    $("#paypal").click(function() {
        $(".yhteystiedot").slideUp(600);
        $(".toimitustapa").slideDown(600);
        $('form :input').val("");
        $('.supernappula').html("Maksa PayPalissa");
        $('.supernappula').addClass("simpleCart_checkout");
        $('.supernappula').attr("id", "checkoutbtn");
    }); 
    $("#tilisiirto").click(function() {
        $(".yhteystiedot").slideDown(600);
        $(".toimitustapa").slideDown(600);
        $('.supernappula').html("Tee tilisiirto");
        $('.supernappula').removeClass("simpleCart_checkout");
        $('.supernappula').attr("id", "tilisiirtobtn");

    }); 
    $("#postiennakko").click(function() {
        $(".yhteystiedot").slideDown(600);
        $(".toimitustapa").slideDown(600);
        $('.supernappula').html("Maksa postiennakolla");
        $('.supernappula').removeClass("simpleCart_checkout");
        $('.supernappula').attr("id", "postiennakkobtn");

    });


    $("#matkahuolto").click(function(){
        $(".maksu").slideDown(600);

    });
    $("#posti").click(function(){
        $(".maksu").slideDown(600);

    });

});
```

And the button itself without modifications:

`<button type="button" id="checkoutbtn" class="simpleCart_checkout supernappula"></button>`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcaEg/2/) of the whole page.

If anyone understands?

Comment: when jQuery loads, theres no such thing as #tilisiirtobtn. You could try binding it like this `$("#tilisiirtobtn").live('click',fucnction() {});` because you add that id for it after DOM is ready

Comment: Yeah, when it loads, but #checkoutbtn is modified to #tilisiirtobtn...

Comment: But doing this actually works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely resolution to this is that you need to use jQuery's `live` function rather than `click`.

With the click handler, it registers everything on the page as it is and does not register the event for elements in the future which will have the given selector.

`live`solves this problem by adding the event handler to all elements now, and in the future.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Changing this line:

`$("#tilisiirtobtn").click(function() {`

to

`$("#tilisiirtobtn").live('click', function() {`

Should solve your problem.

[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcaEg/3/)

Comment: Just glad you've got it sorted, whoever the answer came from first :)

Comment: my thoughts exactly, well explained. +1

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 0):

You're double calling document ready. All you need is `$(function()...` not the wrapper of `$(document).ready(function() {` you've put around it.

Comment: @Dipaks, actually there was a double document ready, one was in a submitorder.js and one on the itself. Fixed that. However, that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Really I tried it out and it seemed to work, maybe I misunderstood the question and tried the wrong thing. What was meant to be fixed?

Comment: I was trying to modify an element that didn't exist when the page was loaded.